# First user logs in using X11, switch user logs in using Wayland

Tags: login, xorg, gdm, wayland, switch-user

I would like to use X11 for all user logins on my Ubuntu 22.04 setup so I uncommented `WaylandEnable=false` in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.

After a reboot, the first user logs in and `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` is x11. When that user goes to the top right menu > Power Off/Log Out > Switch User... then selects another user and enters the password there is no gear icon. When that second user logs in `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` is wayland.

The same result if I log out both users, then have the users log in using a different order (e.g. Alice then Bob vs Bob then Alice). The first user to log in gets x11, stays logged in, goes to Switch User..., that second user to log in gets wayland.

I tried adding `DefaultSession=ubuntu-xorg.desktop` to /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and when switching users the second user to log in sees a gear icon when entering their password with the options: Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` shows wayland after choosing either option.

Additional info about my setup:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: Please file a bug report if this bug still affects you